# RuntimeError: tf.metrics.mean_iou is not supported when eager execution is enabled

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to get the mean IOU metric between two sets of bounding boxes. I'm running into this error:

> RuntimeError: tf.metrics.mean_iou is not supported when eager execution is enabled.

Reproducible code that throws the error:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = [[0.462, 0.465, 0.492, 0.58],
     [0.435, 0.385, 0.462, 0.467],
     [0.586, 0.449, 0.627, 0.616],
     [0.431, 0.671, 0.494, 0.8],
     [0.519, 0.282, 0.586, 0.449]]

b = [[0.465, 0.467, 0.491, 0.586],
     [0.432, 0.488, 0.464, 0.59],
     [0.585, 0.442, 0.633, 0.625],
     [0.429, 0.664, 0.493, 0.805],
     [0.524, 0.502, 0.594, 0.642]]

tf.compat.v1.metrics.mean_iou(a, b, num_classes=1)
```

What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = [[0.462, 0.465, 0.492, 0.58],
     [0.435, 0.385, 0.462, 0.467],
     [0.586, 0.449, 0.627, 0.616],
     [0.431, 0.671, 0.494, 0.8],
     [0.519, 0.282, 0.586, 0.449]]

b = [[0.465, 0.467, 0.491, 0.586],
     [0.432, 0.488, 0.464, 0.59],
     [0.585, 0.442, 0.633, 0.625],
     [0.429, 0.664, 0.493, 0.805],
     [0.524, 0.502, 0.594, 0.642]]

metric = tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU(num_classes=1)
print(metric(a, b))
>> tf.Tensor(1.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

[This](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/MeanIoU) documentation page explains the MeanIoU metric in more detail, but I think the code snippet above will work for you.